# circle image css with border on top of circle image

Tags: image, css, border, geometry

Hello I would like to create a thick semi opaque border inverted around a css circle image.

This my css code:

```css
.circle {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 99em;
  -moz-border-radius: 99em;
  border-radius: -99em;
  
  border-bottom: -5px solid rgba(214, 11, 82, 0.73);
  border-top: -5px solid rgba(214, 11, 82, 0.73);
  border-left:  -5px solid rgba(214, 11, 82, 0.73);
  border-right: -5px solid rgba(214, 11, 82, 0.73);    
}
```

```html
 <div class="circle" style="background-image: 
       url('http://hk.helpstore.co.uk/images/intro.jpg')">
</div>
```

Comment: What is an *inverted* border? Do you mean *inset* border?

Comment: There is no such thing as a negative or inset border.

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of "circle image"? Do you mean you want the image to appear as a circle?

Comment: is this what you look for ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKXKYe

Comment: @GCyrillus - Very impressive!  :D  You should post it as an answer.

Comment: To have a image as a circle and have a border over it.

Answer (score 2):

To create the inset transparent border you're looking for, you'll need to use an inset box shadow.

```css
.circle {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 99em;
  -moz-border-radius: 99em;
  border-radius: -99em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px rgba(214, 11, 82, 0.73);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle" style="background-image: 
       url('http://hk.helpstore.co.uk/images/intro.jpg')">
</div>
```

Comment: I like this solution better than the one I posted (and deleted).  Yet, I guess OP needs to explain the meaning of "circle image".  Inset and a large radius do not seem to mix well.

Answer (score 0):

Border Css have to include

```
<div class="circle" style="background-image: 
       url('http://hk.helpstore.co.uk/images/intro.jpg')">
</div>

<style>
.circle {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 1em auto;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 99em;
    border: 10px solid black;
}</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**ok, that was clarified a few hours ago** 
 So you may use an `inset` and  unblured `box-shadow` to draw a `border`like on the inside edge of your circle.

```css
.circle {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  border-radius: 99em;
  box-shadow:inset  0 0 0   25px rgba(214, 11, 82, 0.73);    /* size increase to 25 pxfor demo purpose */
}
```

```html
<div class="circle" style="background-image: 
       url('http://hk.helpstore.co.uk/images/intro.jpg')">
</div>
```

---

**PREVIOUS ANSWER BEFORE CLARIFICATION that i keep here**

---

not too sure if this is what you look for:

*Pseudo elements and shadows are layed hover
 to hide and fake borders*

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 3em;
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  /* border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(214, 11, 82, 0.73);
  border-top:5px solid rgba(214, 11, 82, 0.73);
  border-left:  5px solid rgba(214, 11, 82, 0.73);
  border-right: 5px solid rgba(214, 11, 82, 0.73);  */
}
.circle:before,
.circle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.circle:before {
  background: white;
  left: -80px;
  box-shadow: 5px 0 rgba(214, 11, 82, 0.73), 505px 0 white, 500px 0 rgba(214, 11, 82, 0.73);
  z-index: 1;
}
.circle:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: white;
  top: -100px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px rgba(214, 11, 82, 0.73), 0 550px white, 0 545px rgba(214, 11, 82, 0.73);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle" style="background-image: 
       url('http://hk.helpstore.co.uk/images/intro.jpg')">
</div>
```

Comment: The image is not a circle.

Comment: @KavKhalsa i know it is not, you had to clarify what 'inverted' meant to you., i see now you did a few hours ago ...

Comment: answer updated to set a border like inside the circle over the bg-image. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.borderimg { 
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    padding: 15px;
background-color:pink;
  -webkit-border-image: url(border.png) 30 round; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
    -o-border-image: url(border.png) 30 round; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<body class="w3-container">


<img src="http://i.imgur.com/lGq1IXo.png" class="w3-circle w3-border borderimg" alt="" style="width:50%">

</body>
</html>
```